# Missing form input field

Tags: html, forms

Anyone know why this input field isn't appearing: http://plnkr.co/edit/TKRtkjqRjuVcT9rcmKW1?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    Input: <intput type="text"/>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: @DavidBrierton - awesome!  Guess it's time for a delete unless others find this question useful.  I'm sure the haters will be by soon.

Comment: Happens to the best of us

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a type error with your input field.